# How to print all elements that belongs_to this table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, belongs-to

Ok, I'm not sure that my title was clear enough, but I will try to explain

I have two tables: orders that has_many items and items that belongs_to orders.
I just started to learn RoR and stuck with a simple task. All I want is to 
display orders and related items like this:

Order 1:
  Item 1
  Item 2
Order 2:
  Item 1
  Item 2
...

I know how to display orders or items separately, I know how to display items' orders (item.order.id), but how to display orders and items in the table like above? In template where I display orders I could go through each item every iteration and compare it foreign order_id with order.id, but that would be awkward. I'm supposing that I should get items into some kind of multidimensional hash where key would be order_id and then I could just refer to this hash by order id and get all items in it, but I'm not sure it's correct.

I hope what I have written here is understandable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define a `has_many` relation, you automatically get the methods to query those objects. In this case, the method `order.items`.

So you can do:

```
Order.find_each do |order|
  puts "Order #{order.id}:"
  order.items.each do |item|
    puts "Item #{item.id}"
  end
end
```

(I used [find_each](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/ClassMethods/find_each) method, which is available from Rails 2.3+. You could use a simple `Order.all.each` though.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! But if I want to use it in a template, it won't work, right? It says undefined method 'items'.

Comment: It should work, assuming you are correctly calling on an object of type `Order`. How exactly are you calling it in your view?

Comment: <% Order.all.each do |order|  %>

Comment: Ok, I got it. It works. Should have been 'item' not 'items'. Thanks a lot!